# How can I make Relu activation in tensorflow.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am now making an agent for DQN.
I implemented Relu activation funcitons like this:

```
self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.action_size)
])
```

When I compute gradients, the some of gradients become zero.
I thought that was becasue of RELU. 
So I changed it as:

```
self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.action_size)
])
```

Then it worked well.

But when I make this code low-level tensorflow like this:

```
self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.state_size])
self.layer1=tf.layers.dense(self.X,20,activation=tf.nn.relu)
self.output_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.layer1,self.action_size)
self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.action_size])
```

The relu activation worked well. I mean the gradients was not all zeros.
I don't know why the result of first implementation is not same as the result of last implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ReLU functions: LeakyLeakyReLU and Parametric PReLU together with the default ReLU in keras. You need to check what are the default parameters for both of these. For instance: [keras.layers.LeakyReLU](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/) default parameter alpha is 0.3.

Gradients may become 0 because the neuron parameters are randomly set at the very start and this may cause the issues you had.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The situation that gradients of hidden layer are zero always happen. And I use same initializer in all cases.
I think the first and the last are exactly same except whether using keras or not.
So, I don't know why the gradients of hidden layers are zero in the first case.

Comment: I figured it out. 
I did not use tf.keras.layers.ReLU() instead add activation = tf.nn.relu to tf.keras.layers.Dense